# C# and matlab give different image means?

Tags: c#, matlab

I am calculating the average of the RGB channels of images in C# and matlab and getting slightly different result??  (am using 0-255 pixel values...)

The difference is not large but I just can't seem to understand the reason...

Is this common?? Or is it due to bitmap implementation of image?? Or precision issue?? Or does it mean their is something wrong with my code??

Code:

Matlab

```
I = imread('Photos\hv2512.jpg');
Ir=double(I(:,:,1));
Ig=double(I(:,:,2));
Ib=double(I(:,:,3));


avRed=mean2(Ir)
avGn=mean2(Ig)
avBl=mean2(Ib)
```

C#

```
        Bitmap bmp= new Bitmap(open.FileName)
        double[,] Red = new double[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
        double[,] Green = new double[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
        double[,] Blue = new double[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];

        int PixelSize = 3;
        BitmapData bmData = null;

        if (Safe)
        {
            Color c;

            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
                {
                    c = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
                    Red[i, j] =   (double) c.R;
                    Green[i, j] = (double) c.G;
                    Blue[i, j] =  (double) c.B;



                }
            }
        }
            double avRed = 0, avGrn = 0, avBlue = 0;
            double sumRed = 0, sumGrn = 0, sumBlue = 0;
            int cnt = 0;

            for (int rws = 0; rws < Red.GetLength(0); rws++)
                for (int clms = 0; clms < Red.GetLength(1); clms++)
                {
                    sumRed = sumRed + Red[rws, clms];
                    sumGrn = sumGrn + Green[rws, clms];
                    sumBlue = sumBlue + Blue[rws, clms];

                    cnt++;
                }


            avRed = sumRed / cnt;
            avGrn = sumGrn / cnt;
            avBlue = sumBlue / cnt;
```

[This is the image I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkuER.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your code to let the community examine it. What do you mean by "RGB average" by the way?

Comment: Bitmaps are uncompressed so there is no ambiguity at all when it comes to reading in the colours and/or associated colour map.  (1), where's the code you wrote between both to compute the average? (2) Are you trying to compute the average over the **entire** image, or in image blocks? (3) How are you getting a **negative** average when intensities are strictly positive? (4) Where is the image you are using?

Comment: I am getting negative numbers for average of the wavelet subbands but for the RGB channels as well I get the same thing...

Comment: You're not finding the average of RGB images. You are finding the average of wavelet coefficients determined by images.  This isn't clear in your post.  We need to see code.  Not doing this will inevitably make your post closed.  We aren't here to read your mind or try and debug code when it's non-existent.  Please read here on how to ask a proper question, and edit your question to conform to this standard: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added the code,,, Just the average of the RGB channels

Comment: You're using a JPEG image.  I thought you were using a Bitmap image.  That's why you see a difference in pixel values.  Different frameworks decompress JPEGs differently, so you'll definitely see a difference between frameworks.  You can't expect them to be the same, so if you are, use a lossless compression standard instead, like PNG.